# yii cdbexpression expression with alias error

Tags: php, yii

I have following code

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->with = array('owner'=>array('select'=>array('*','payment_info'=>'payment_account')));
```

which works fine, but when i add concat into it

```
$criteria->with = array('owner'=>array('select'=>array('*','payment_info'=>'concat(payment_account)')));
```

it throws me an error

```
Active record "User" is trying to select an invalid column "concat(payment_account)". Note, the column must exist in the table or be an expression with alias.
```

how to provide alias for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving it an alias, like:

`$criteria->with = array('owner'=> array('select'=> array('*','payment_info'=>'concat(payment_account) as conc')));`

I've used that method without a problem before.

Comment: ah, the problem was that i not used "as" word, in mysql it is not required

Comment: Yeh I'm not sure why though. Will consider filing it as a bug, it ought put the value into a new attribute named either 'concat(payment_account)' as mysql does for the field name, or use the array key like you gave it.  Anyway, glad it worked.